# Alias of INNER JOIN referred to a column in the field list SQL

Tags: sql, join, alias

I'm really struggling about this.

```
SELECT t1.servizio, 
       Count(DISTINCT p.pro_id), 
       Count(DISTINCT CASE 
                        WHEN Concat(p.pro_id, p.gender) LIKE '%M' THEN p.pro_id 
                      END) AS 'M', 
       Count(DISTINCT CASE 
                        WHEN Concat(p.pro_id, p.gender) LIKE '%F' THEN p.pro_id 
                      END) AS 'F', 
       Count(DISTINCT CASE 
                        WHEN Concat(p.pro_id, p.in_provincia) LIKE '%Si' THEN 
                        p.pro_id 
                      END) AS 'prov_si', 
       Count(DISTINCT CASE 
                        WHEN Concat(p.pro_id, p.in_provincia) LIKE '%No' THEN 
                        p.pro_id 
                      END) AS 'prov_no', 
       Count(DISTINCT t1.pronto_request_id), 
       Count(t2.quote_id) 
FROM   pro p, 
       pro_request pr, 
       request_servizio t1 
       JOIN (SELECT request_servizio.servizio, 
                    Count(quote_request.quote_id) 
             FROM   request_servizio, 
                    quote_request 
             WHERE  request_servizio.pronto_request_id = 
                    quote_request.pronto_request_id 
             GROUP  BY request_servizio.servizio) AS t2 
         ON t1.servizio = t2.servizio 
WHERE  p.pro_id = pr.pro_id 
       AND pr.pronto_request_id = t1.pronto_request_id 
GROUP  BY t1.servizio
```

Basically, I have 4 tables involved: `request_servizio`, `pro`, `pro_request` and `quote_request`.

The problem is with the last selected column:

> the error is "unknown column t2.quote_id..."

But yet `t2` is the alias of the join. So why I got this error?

I tried to include the table `quote_request` which is the one where you can find the last attribute, but I got a wrong aggregation then. How to avoid this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The subquery t2 returns no quote_id column.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax everywhere! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: you are using t2.quote_id but in you subquery you doesn't define the column name. I think   you need to make alias of Count(quote_request.quote_id) as quote_id

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [mcve].  Show that your program calculates what you expect it to as it goes through (sub)expressions by saying what that is & showing that it actually does it via incremental output. Justify "minimal code with a problem" for required functionality by also giving code that works for a maximal part of that functionality. Ask about the (small) difference between the examples. (These are debugging basics.)Do you understand that comma binds looser than JOINs? This matters when OUTER JOINs are present. Mixing implicit (comma) & explicit is asking for trouble.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and you are using invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...  And no, "HeidiSQL" is not a database product, it's a SQL client that can connect to different DBMS products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the JOIN, the subquery you used doesn't provide the column quote_id which means that you can not reference it from the alias t2 as it was not provided in that inner subquery in the select part. You can only use what you give from the inner query.

I would say change the query to this as you already seem to have the count you want to use.

```
SELECT t1.servizio, 
   Count(DISTINCT p.pro_id), 
   Count(DISTINCT CASE 
                    WHEN Concat(p.pro_id, p.gender) LIKE '%M' THEN p.pro_id 
                  END) AS 'M', 
   Count(DISTINCT CASE 
                    WHEN Concat(p.pro_id, p.gender) LIKE '%F' THEN p.pro_id 
                  END) AS 'F', 
   Count(DISTINCT CASE 
                    WHEN Concat(p.pro_id, p.in_provincia) LIKE '%Si' THEN 
                    p.pro_id 
                  END) AS 'prov_si', 
   Count(DISTINCT CASE 
                    WHEN Concat(p.pro_id, p.in_provincia) LIKE '%No' THEN 
                    p.pro_id 
                  END) AS 'prov_no', 
   Count(DISTINCT t1.pronto_request_id), 
   Count(t2.CountOfQuoteId) --edit here
FROM   pro p, 
   pro_request pr, 
   request_servizio t1 
   JOIN (SELECT request_servizio.servizio, 
                Count(quote_request.quote_id) AS CountOfQuoteId --edit here
         FROM   request_servizio, 
                quote_request 
         WHERE  request_servizio.pronto_request_id = 
                quote_request.pronto_request_id 
         GROUP  BY request_servizio.servizio) AS t2 
     ON t1.servizio = t2.servizio 
WHERE  p.pro_id = pr.pro_id 
   AND pr.pronto_request_id = t1.pronto_request_id 
GROUP  BY t1.servizio
```

Also you could change those joins to the newer standard, it is much cleaner and easier to use.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, now it runs correctly. I knew it was a stupid thing, completely forgot to assign an alias within the JOIN